# How to set the placeholder text of the MUI DatePicker?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, date-fns

How can I set the placeholder text of the MUI `DatePicker`. The text that is displayed when deleting the text in the input field. I want to set the text to `"tt.mm.jjjj"` and I always the following error message:

```
Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `j`
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdatepicker-material-demo-forked-657hj?file=/demo.js:410-679)

```
<DatePicker
  inputFormat="tt.mm.jjjj"
    label="Basic example"
    value={value}
    onChange={(newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField placeholder="tt.mm.jjjj" {...params} />}
  />
```

Comment: Where did you import `DatePicker`? Did you check if there's any documentation of what the `inputFormat` prop should be? It seems more likely that it's inputFormat and not placeholder that causes this error.

Comment: @HåkenLid You can check the sandbox example it works for: "dd.mm.yyyy"

Comment: @BENARDPatrick My Question is "How can I set the placeholder text of the mui datepicker." So how can set the text that is shown, when the input is empty? I need a it in the german language: tt.mm.jjjj

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is how you reset the placeholder of the `TextField` inside the `DatePicker`. The reason it doesn't work is because it is overridden by the `params.inputProps` provided by the `DatePicker` itself based on the `inputFormat`:

```
<DatePicker
  {...}
  inputFormat="tt.mm.yyyy"
  renderInput={(params) => {
    console.log(params);
    return (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        inputProps={{
          ...params.inputProps,
          placeholder: "tt.mm.jjjj"
        }}
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Have you found a way to add this to MuiDatePicker theme?

Comment: Thanks a lot, working on September 22.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need to customize `TextField`, You can just use `slotProps` attribute to set the **placehoder** value.

```
<DatePicker
        format="tt.mm.yyyy"
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        slotProps={{ textField: { placeholder: 'tt.mm.jjjj' } }}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
  <TextField
      type="date"
      label="End Date"
      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
       />
```

[type="date" label="your label "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWaa4.png)

```
    <TextField
        type="date"
        label="End Date"
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        name="selectedendDate"
        {...register("selectedendDate", {
          required: "End Date is required.",
           validate: (value) =>
            value >= getValues("selectedstartDate"),
         message: "End Date Must be Less Then Start Date..",
             })}                     
           error={Boolean(errors.selectedendDate)}
           helperText={errors.selectedendDate?.message}
           FormHelperTextProps={helperTextFontSize}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 <Select
          value={priority}
          label="Priority"
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
   />


    <FormControl>
                <InputLabel
                  error={Boolean(errors.priority)}
                  helperText={errors.priority?.message}
                >
                  Priority
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                  value={priority}
                  label="Priority"
                  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setPriority(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  name="priority"
                  inputProps={register("priority", {
                    required: "Story Priority is required.",
                  })}
                  error={Boolean(errors.priority)}
                  helperText={"Hello " + errors.priority?.message}
                >
                  {prioritys.map((resp) => (
                    <MenuItem value={resp}>{resp}</MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
                <FormHelperText
                  style={{ fontSize: fontSizeMessage }}
                  error={Boolean(errors.priority)}
                >
                  {errors.priority?.message}
                </FormHelperText>
              </FormControl>
```