# How Can I add the placeholder (Not Label) to MUI 5 DatePicker?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datepicker

I want to add the placholder to MUI 5 date picker, here is the MUI 5 datepickerlink: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/

****The thing I want to achieve is**: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/31706755?key=096a75ccfcf711b0806280400c10727f**

You can refer me to this chat, but it is not working in my case: [How to set the placeholder text of the MUI DatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525488/how-to-set-the-placeholder-text-of-the-mui-datepicker)

I also **don't want to add label** as the user click in the filed the lable pushed to the border.

So, my requirement is add the placholder text like we can add in the textfiled. I hope now it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add placeholder on input props like this :

```
  <DatePicker
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        inputProps={{
          placeholder: "Placeholder"
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

For MUI DatePicker 6.X versions and up, use `slots` and `slotProps` instead of `inputProps` and `renderInput`.
You can set **placeholder** by using only the `slotProps` attribute.

```
<DatePicker
    {...}
    format="ddd, MMM D YYYY"
    slotProps={{ textField: { placeholder: 'DD/MM/YYYY' } }}
  />
```